# How do I hide Google reCAPTCHA v3 from my site?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I just upgraded from v2 and css is no longer a valid option for hiding the recaptcha badge from my UI. Can this be done with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with recursion and `requestAnimationFrame`.

Try creating something like this:

```
function hideRecaptcha() {
    const recaptcha = $(".grecaptcha-badge");
    if (recaptcha.length) return recaptcha.css({ display: "none" });
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.hideRecaptcha());
}
```

Then call `hideRecaptcha()` immediately after loading the recaptcha script.

Comment: thanks! Just added this code and the recaptcha badge is finally hidden.

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53986985/1729287 answer the `display: none` is disabling the spam check. Also you can must include a reCAPTCHA  branding since you are using it. Check the FAQ https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Answer (score 0):

You should set it to visibility: none because it might disrupt the spam checking if you use display none and remove it completely.

See here.
[How to hide the Google Invisible reCAPTCHA badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543157/how-to-hide-the-google-invisible-recaptcha-badge)