# Load nuxt 3 plugin only on specific page

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a nuxt3 app, and i want to add recaptcha to the registration form.

Im using  `vue-recaptcha-v3` package, like this in `plugins/google-recaptcha.ts`:

```
import { VueReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueReCaptcha, {
    siteKey: config.public.recaptchaKey,
    loaderOptions: {
      autoHideBadge: false,
      explicitRenderParameters: {
        badge: 'bottomleft'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that i want the plugin to load only on the registration page, nowhere else. Any way to do this?

Comment: This is probably not done at nuxt level but at plugin level. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70419078/11258206) answer to a similar question. In particular `recaptcha.hideBadge()`.

Comment: that way the plugin would be still loaded. I guess the way is to include the native google script on the specific page, and not using the vue-recaptcha-v3 package.

As a workaround for now i used this in the plugin.
`
if (!authStore.isLoggedIn()) {
 nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueReCaptcha...
}
`
Its important to say that this will only work if the page is reloaded after login/registration, otherwise plugins would not "refresh".